# Problem unzipping pdf file with special character (in pdf) in a flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, decode, encode

please
I'm not able to find a solution to unzip a .zip file that has a pdf with accent in name, something like:

name.zip -> nâmé.pdf.

It's not something I can handle when saving the file because the exception is already generated when I call decoder:

```
import 'package:archive/archive.dart';
final zipFile = File(await projectFilePath() + zipFilename);
      final destinationDir = Directory(await projectUnzipFilePath()).path;

      // Read the Zip file from disk.
      final bytes = zipFile.readAsBytesSync();

      // Decode the Zip file
      final archive = ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(bytes);
```

In "ZipDecoder" thorw a Encode exception.

Comment: Unfortunately there are already thousands of files zipped on the server with the internal files with accents. I didn't find any lib for this, I'm almost buying the fight to tell the backend to turn around and send the unzipped file

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem with a regex that strips the special characters, thus renaming the file before doing any processing.

Answer (score -1):

somethin like this init

```
   try {
    // code that might throw an exception
    }
    catch(e){
    // code for handling exception
    }
```